# Why can't get validation in chosen accordion form element?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, accordion

I have an issue with BS modal (im using BS 3) and it is confirming form submission. But it is placed in accordion and when i click e.g. 5th element modal and validator works but shows error in first element. I dont know what can be the problem, maybe data-toggle is mixed (modal and validator).Below I put that part of code (with erased loop and other things connected with template viewer -> smarty)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div id="accordion_dotacja">
    <b>Udostępnij kod pracownikowi:</b> <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9" style="padding-right:0;">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="" style="border-top-right-radius: 0; border-bottom-right-radius: 0;" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:0;">
        <button class="btn button btn-info" style="border-top-left-radius: 0; border-bottom-left-radius: 0;">Kopiuj kod</button>
      </div>
    </div><br>
    <b>Albo załóż konto pracownika:</b> <br><br>
    <form id="myForm" action="" method="post" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          Imię:<br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee_name" data-error="Proszę podać imię." required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          Nazwisko:<br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee_surname" data-error="Proszę podać nazwisko." required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          Numer telefonu:<br>
          <input placeholder="9-cyfrowy numer telefonu" type="text" class="form-control" name="employee_phone" data-error="Proszę podać numer telefonu" pattern="[0-9]{9}" required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          Adres e-mail:<br>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="employee_email" data-error="Proszę podać prawidłowy adres e-mail." required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_employee">
      <input type="hidden" name="kurs_id" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="">
      <input type="button" name="btn" value="Utwórz" id="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit" class="btn button btn-primary" />
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p class="body" style="font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: 400;">
            <b> Klikając &bdquo;Załóż konto/Aplikuj&rdquo; akceptujesz
                                <a href="/regulamin" target="_blank">Regulamin Serwisu</a> i potwierdzasz, że zapoznałeś się z
                                <a href="/polityka_prywatnosci" target="_blank">Polityką ochrony prywatności</a> oraz
                                <a href="/cookie" target="_blank">Polityką Cookies</a>.
                            </b>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" form="myForm" class="btn btn-success col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">Załóż konto/Aplikuj
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I dont use any js file to this (only the validator, but its default code).
To clarify whats going on with this problem i attach video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pYwLbxyZTZUFiGXny5LdO9Zg1S9_jKnr/view?usp=sharing

Earlier the code was without modals an validator was working correctly e.g i click submit on 5th element and validator runs in this element and so on.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div id="accordion_dotacja">
  <div>
    <b>Udostępnij kod pracownikowi:</b> <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9" style="padding-right:0;">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="hash_{$v.id}" style="border-top-right-radius: 0; border-bottom-right-radius: 0;" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:0;">
        <button class="btn button btn-info" style="border-top-left-radius: 0; border-bottom-left-radius: 0;">Kopiuj kod</button>
      </div>
    </div><br>
    <b>Albo załóż konto pracownika:</b> <br><br>
    <form action="" method="post" data-toggle="validator" role="form" onsubmit="return confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz założyć konto pracownikowi?');">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          Imię:<br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee_name" data-error="Proszę podać imię." required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          Nazwisko:<br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee_surname" data-error="Proszę podać nazwisko." required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          Numer telefonu:<br>
          <input placeholder="9-cyfrowy numer telefonu" type="text" class="form-control" name="employee_phone" data-error="Proszę podać numer telefonu" pattern="[0-9]{9}" required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          Adres e-mail:<br>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="employee_email" data-error="Proszę podać prawidłowy adres e-mail." required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_employee">
      <input type="hidden" name="kurs_id" value="{$i}">
      <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="{$v.hash}">
      <input type="submit" class="btn button btn-primary" value="Utwórz">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[production code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbrtE.png)

[version of bootstrap - 3.3.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlebf.png)

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: I added few more informations what you mentioned :)

Comment: Your title still isn't specific (nor a question), and you haven't added the tags as I asked. We're looking at code and have to guess what it is.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: please tell me what can be done , to improve the visibility :) Now i have 2 code snippets with removed smarty variables (because they wont work there)

Comment: I still don't know what validation you are actually talking about here, or how it gets triggered.